# Unable to change innodb_buffer_pool_size MySQL 5.6 in CentOS 6.7

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, memory, my.cnf, centos

I have searched all over but couldn't find where **service mysqld restart** picks up the configuration file from:

```
sudo find / -name "*.cnf" | grep my

/usr/share/doc/mysql-community-server-5.6.33/my-default.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-default.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf
```

My MySQL 5.6.33 is running on 1 GB of InnoDB Buffer Pool whereas none of these files has that setting. I have setting

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
```

in the file copied from /usr/share/mysql/my-default.cnf to /etc/my.cnf - I did this:

```
service mysqld restart --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
```

Still not working.

Comment: Post output of following: show global variables like 'innodb_buffer%';

Comment: grep innodb /etc/my.cnf

Comment: @mysql_user - 'grep innodb /etc/my.cnf' gives me innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G but show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' gives me 134217728;

Comment: Check to be sure about my.cnf used as follows:         mysqld –verbose –help | grep -C1 my.cnf

Comment: Also your error log will confirm "initializing innocent buffer pool..... "

Comment: And I do not know for sure if "service" take arguments... never did that!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

- About     `Service mysqld start --defaults-file=..`

AFAIK it isn't correct way to pass argument. It should not be accepting that argument.
Never done that; importantly it isn't even necessary for default location!!!

- Confirm the which my.cnf is being used:

`mysqld –verbose –help | grep -C1 my.cnf`

- Confirm we have correct entry in my.cnf

`grep innodb_buffer_pool_size /etc/my.cnf`

- Verify your error log, you should see something like

`InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool size = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set global innodb buffer pool size

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=4294967296;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html

Comment: I did mention that I am using MySQL 5.6 - in MySQL 5.6, you can't change InnoDB Buffer Pool Size online.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`.

Since I was reducing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, it became less than one 1GB per instance, so it ended up rounding it.

When I also reduced the *instances*, it finally changed the *pool size*!